# non-temporary rvalue design pattern?

Tags: c++, rvalue

I'm writing a C++ matrix-like class that allocates memory and has methods (e.g. `row()`, `col()`) that returns views of itself referencing the same memory via `shared_ptr`.

e.g.

```
Matrix Matrix::row(int r)
```

The fundamental problem is that C++ regards an expression such as `m.row(0)` to be an rvalue whereas the return type of `row()` is not a self-contained temporary that can be moved but rather a view (with shared memory) into the non-temporary parent matrix.

The problem manifests whenever I want to use move semantics such as:

```
Matrix add(const Matrix &a, const Matrix &b);

Matrix add(Matrix &&a, Matrix &&b);
```

If I write `add(m.row(0), m.row(1))` then the compiler will call the rvalue version of `add()` which may modify it's *temporary* parameters and therefore the non-temporary parent matrix m! :-(

I don't want to avoid rvalues and always pass by value instead:

```
Matrix add(Matrix a, Matrix b);
```

Since although this handles the rvalue case efficiently (via move construction), it also means I'm always copying non-rvalues which is inefficient.

I also don't want to make the return type of `row()` const since I want to be able to treat it as an lvalue:

```
m.row(0) = m.row(1);
```

I've considered explicitly testing whether rvalue parameters are views via `shared_ptr` `use_count()`, but this seems messy since the whole point of rvalues is that it's meant to be a type signature of temporary values that are inherently modifiable.

Can anyone suggest a design pattern for this type of situation where a function return value is a non-temporary value (such as a view onto something else), but you also want to use rvalue optimizations?

Comment: Create a class called `MatrixView` that holds a matrix, and defines its own copy/move ctors and operators so that you can get all the sharing you want.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I've tried using a separate view class, but since I want to be able to use matrix views anywhere I use matrices (e.g. pass to add()) I had the MatrixView class being derived from Matrix which means that MatrixView&& is passable to Matrix&& :-(

Comment: This is unclear. It sounds like you use the same class name `Matrix` to represent both a matrix, and a view onto a different matrix.   If so, stop doing this - use a different class name for each. (And don't use inheritance).  If you want a function to accept a view, then declare to to accept a view. You can provide an implicit conversion operator from matrix to view if you want.

Comment: `T add(T lhs, T const &rhs);` is the usual signature for an addition function, with the body doing `lhs += rhs; return lhs;`

Comment: Thanks MM. How exactly would you define the view class to avoid this problem? I've tried a view class derived from matrix which allows me to pass both to functions like add(), but doesn't help the rvalue problem. If I derive both matrix and view from a common base class, and define all functions to take the base type then I avoid the rvalue issue but it becomes messy in terms of having to mix const Base& and Matrix&& types to optimize. Your addition function prototype doesn't help in cases like add(x, add(y, z)) where it'd be more optimal to do rhs += lhs; return (rhs).

Comment: MM, I don't see how this use of types helps. If the view generating functions, e.g. row(), return some view type, and any rvalue-optimized functions, e.g. add(), have an rvalue reference parameter that accepts rvalue reference to the same view type, then the problem still exists.

Comment: @SpinyNormam: Still create a MatrixView class that holds onto a Matrix resource, but create an `operator Matrix` so that it has implicit conversion to an actual Matrix. In this way you have full control over how the held Matrix object is shared (or not). Deriving is not necessary.

Comment: @AndyG: That works as far as the rvalue problem, but the trouble is that my matrix (tensor, actually) class is fairly complex, having 300+ member functions, and I'd like those member functions to be available for views as well. If I don't use inheritence than I'd have to reimplement them all in the view class (albeit only as pass-thrus).

Comment: Having thought about this some more, I'm thinking of inverting the relationship between maxtix and view and having MatrixView (implementing all the core functionality) being the base class, with Matrix derived from MatrixView... This way, Matrix is convertible to MatrixView, but not vice versa, so I can use const MatrixView& as my default read-only parameter type and Matrix&& for rvalue optimization.